# How to save dates for a specific user

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to insert data in a table where I can track the first print date(PrintDate) and the latest print date (RePrint) of the specific persons and save the dates where I first printed and the latest print into my database.

My database looks like this

[image: db]

```
 INSERT INTO PrintTable (PrintDate, RePrint) 
VALUES
  (
    '2019-07-25 10:37:46',
    '2019-07-25 10:37:49'
  ) 
  ON DUPLICATE KEY 
  UPDATE 
    PrintDate = '2017-07-25 10:37:46',
    RePrint = '2019-07-25 10:37:49' 
  WHERE MEMB_N = '000002';
```

This is the error that I got:

> Query: INSERT INTO PrintTable (PrintDate, RePrint) VALUES ( '2017-07-25 10:37:46', '2019-07-25 10:37:49' ) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Prin...

Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE MEMB_N = '000002'' at line 11

> Error Code: 1064
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE MEMB_N = 'The specific user number'' at line 11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ON DUPLICATE KEY` does not allow a where clause and it is not needed because MySQL already know which record has to be updated : it is the one that generated the `DUPLICATED KEY`
The INSERT part of you query is wrong because it implies that the unique constraint is set on `{PrintDate, Reprint}`. I guess it is actually on `MEMB_N`
So your query should be

```sql
 INSERT INTO PrintTable (MEMB_N, PrintDate, RePrint) 
VALUES
  (
    '000002',
    '2019-07-25 10:37:46',
    '2019-07-25 10:37:49'
  ) 
  ON DUPLICATE KEY 
  UPDATE 
    PrintDate = '2017-07-25 10:37:46',
    RePrint = '2019-07-25 10:37:49';
```

It means : try to insert a new record for `MEMB_N = '000002'`. If this record already exists then update `PrintDate` and `RePrint` for this record.